# Not able to call a controller method through jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and  not able to call a controller method through jquery ajax, where the method fetch data from database in codeigniter
in controller class passing $data variable to view page.Its working fine without using ajax .

```
public function get_chat()
{
    $this->load->model('chat_model');
    if($query = $this->chat_model->get_msg())
    {
        $data["records"] = $query;
    }
    $this->load->view('view_chat',$data);
}
```

in model class

```
    public function get_msg()
{   
    $data = array("sender_id"=>1);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('chat');
    $this->db->where($data);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

script used to call the controller method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('Chat/get_chat'); ?>",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#message").html(data);

    }
},1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: status code showing 200 ,but the page is not viewing

Comment: Well as usual, test that your method is being called by simply sending something basic back without the database bits to establish whether that is working or not. ie. Hello World!

Comment: if you access get_chat directly does the view render ?, why are doing a post request?

Comment: TimBrownlaw  ,method is working ..,but not able to view page

Comment: if iload the view page in index method its working ,but if i remove and load view inside controller method and passed to ajax url its showing blank